# How can you remove chatango chat X button?

Tags: html, widget, embed

There is a X button on chatango widgets which if user clicks on it, the chat box will disappear and there is no way you can have chat again, 
I checked the embed codes guide in chatango room configuration, I found this: "showx Show close button" I insert "showx":0 into my page's script tag, in brackets right the place it should be

{"handle":"eurousd","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"000066","b":62,"c":"000000","bpos":"tl","d":"000000","e":"ffffff","f":62,"h":"ffffff","i":62,"k":"3366ff","l":"3366ff","m":"3366ff","o":62,"q":"3366ff","r":62,"sbc":"bbbbbb","surl":0,"allowpm":0,"fwtickm":1,"pos":"bl","showx":0}}

but still shows that x button :/
do you know how can i remove that?

Answer (score 0):

I created an `<a>` to overlap the X button:

```
<a class="bugfix" href="URL TO YOUR CHAT BOX" target="_blank"></a>
```

Then, this to your CSS:

```
.bugfix {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: #242731;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Note that your chat needs to have `position: relative;`. You can do that by wrapping the `<script>` inside a `<div>` then you can use CSS.

Comment: please also write your <div> and show an example of "URL TO YOUR CHAT BOX"

Comment: @Micheal URL to your chat box is the URL to your chat room on chatango.com.
https://example.chatango.com for example.

Comment: I succeed to remove X button, but now the chat has become unselectable!

Comment: That has to do with something else. My method only adds a div on top of the X button.